# MVC strongly typed view data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a strongly typed view that creates the form fields like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

That's fine, X in the above lambda expression relates to a class I've created with a property of 'Name'.

How do I use this same view but have access to the properties of a different class? For example if you imagine I've another class called - UserDetails, and email address is a property of that. How can I do this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

within the same strongly typed view?

Comment: You pass your new model along the new view using your action that calls the corresponding view and it is ok!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, how do I pass a new model along a new view?

Comment: you can have base class that has both models common proprties and then ceate a view for that, then in your view you can cast the type and load another partial view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In asp.net mvc you pass model to view like this:

```
    public ActionResult Base()
        {
            return View(new DerviedOne());
        }
```

And here is your models definitions :

```
  public class BaseModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerviedOne : BaseModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerviedTwo : BaseModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you have to create three views:

Base View:

```
@using Models
@model Models.BaseModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Base";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Base</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>BaseModel</h4>
        <hr/>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Id)
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    if(Model is DerviedOne)
     {
         Html.RenderPartial("DerviedOneView", Model as DerviedOne);
     }

    if (Model is DerviedTwo)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("DerviedTwoView", Model as DerviedTwo);
    }
}
```

Second view:

```
@model WebApplication.Models.DerviedOne

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DerviedOne</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Third view:

```
@model WebApplication.Models.DerviedTwo

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DerviedTwo</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```